# Set div-element's position depending on wheelscroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position, mousewheel

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  animate_in();
});

function animate_in() {
  addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
    var targetCube = $('.cube-container.cube-0');
    var wScroll = event.deltaY/100;
    var currentPosition = targetCube.offset().top;
    var newPosition = currentPosition + wScroll;
    console.log(currentPosition)
    targetCube.css({
      'top' : newPosition
    });
    console.log(newPosition)
  });
}
```

```css
section .wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
section .wrapper a.cube-container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  background: pink;
}
section .wrapper a.cube-container:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
section .wrapper a.cube-0{
  top: -200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class = "cube-container cube-0" href="")>
      <div class="box cube-0">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have an element set with CSS to be outside the page. I'm trying to animate it in using javascript. The page it self is not srollable so I'm catching wheel scroll. To make this work I do this:

- On `$( document ).ready` I load the function where I add `EventListener`;
- I get the element;
- I extract it's current position;
- I get wheel deltaY;
- I calculate the new position;
- I set the element's css top value to the new calculated position.

All seems to be working but for some reason when I sroll once again it's position jumps on certain value (the element size depends on window dimensions and with each dimension the number differs). I checked it's not element height. I don't access or change it's position elsewhere. But next time the event happens the value is already different (currentPosition of next event is not the same as newPosition on the previous one).

Here is the function:

```
function animate_in() {
  addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
    var targetCube = $('.cube-container.cube-0');
    var wScroll = event.deltaY/1000;
    var currentPosition = targetCube.offset().top;
    var newPosition = currentPosition + wScroll;
    targetCube.css({
      'top' : newPosition
    });
  });
}
```

If I substract the number deduced using console.log of old and new positions of several events from this line:

```
var newPosition = currentPosition + wScroll - CONSTANTDIFFERENCE;
```

-I get it to sroll right, but when I resize the screen the number changes and I can't see the patern.

And here are the logs of position before and after:
With one screen size:

```
scripts.js:41 -515.5
scripts.js:45 -515.475
scripts.js:41 -430.96875
scripts.js:45 -430.94375
scripts.js:41 -346.4375
scripts.js:45 -346.4125
```

the difference is constant: 84,50625.

And with another sreen size (bigger):

```
scripts.js:41 -374.5
scripts.js:45 -374.475
scripts.js:41 -148.96875
scripts.js:45 -148.94375
scripts.js:41 76.5625
scripts.js:45 76.5875
```

the difference is constant again but different: 225,50625.

Any ideas where does this number come from or maybe what am I doing wrong? Or maybe you know a way to do it another way?

Comment: It would help me if you could provide a demo using [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something like it that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Added a snippet. The effect is simillar but on a smaller scale - every time the event fires up the currentPosition is not the same as it was left at the end of previous event by newPosition.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is because offset().top gives absolute offset from the DOM and the top was setting value relative to the .wrapper element it was nested in. Thus adding:

```
var offsetElement =       $( '.wrapper' );
var offsetPosition =      offsetElement.offset().top;
```

And rewriting this:

```
var newPosition =         currentPosition + wScroll - offsetPosition;
```

I got it to scroll smothly.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  animate_in();
});

function animate_in() {
  addEventListener('wheel', function(event){
    var targetCube = $('.cube-container.cube-0');
    var wScroll = event.deltaY/5;
    var currentPosition = targetCube.offset().top;
    var offsetElement =       $( '.wrapper' );
    var offsetPosition =      offsetElement.offset().top;
    var newPosition =         currentPosition + wScroll - offsetPosition;
    console.log(currentPosition)
    targetCube.css({
      'top' : newPosition
    });
    console.log(newPosition)
  });
}
```

```css
section .wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
section .wrapper a.cube-container{
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  background: pink;
}
section .wrapper a.cube-container:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
section .wrapper a.cube-0{
  top: -200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class = "cube-container cube-0" href="")>
      <div class="box cube-0">
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```